# Enable datagrid dynamic data at runtime

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I have a data grid using dynamic data. I 'enable' dynamic data on the page_init event for the page containing the data grid. I would like to be able to set the type of the dynamic data at run time. I have the name of the class to set, as a string. I can't quite figure out how to do this.

I set the dynamic data like this:

```
Dim myGrid As GridView = DirectCast(retrieveGrid.FindControl("gridResults"), GridView) 
myGrid.EnableDynamicData(GetType(*MyEntityNameAsAString*)
```

Obviously this does not work because I cannot provide my entity name a s a string. How can I convert the string to the entity type? I tried:

```
Type.GetType(entityname)
```

And

```
Type.GetType(AssemblyName.entityname)
```

And neither seems to work. That is, I can't get the type with either of these statements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it like this... I created a function to get the entity object from the object name:

```
Public Function GetEntity(ByVal entityName As String) As Object
    'Get the assembly
    Dim assem As Assembly = Nothing
    assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/bin/AsbestosEntities.dll")
    'Get all classes in the assembly
    Dim AllEntities As Type() = assem.GetTypes()
    Return AllEntities.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.FullName = entityName)
End Function
```

Then set the grid enable dynamic data based on the result of the function:

```
Dim EntityType As Type = GetEntity(general_retrieve.gr_entity_set_name)
myGrid.EnableDynamicData(EntityType)
```